# number of times event happened with in given time interval

Tags: java, spring

I have a use case to stop a process if particular event occur 'X' times with in a given time interval.

Is there a mechanism in java spring framework to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

The question is quite general, so some general advice:

1. Use a `TreeSet<Long>` of timestamps when the event happened;
2. at each event occurence, add its timestamp to the set and remove all the expired entries  (older than timeout);
3. react when the set size grows above your threshold.

For 2. use the `tailSet` method to quickly eliminate the expired timestamps.

This is a short example of the approach:

```
public class OverloadGuard {
  private SortedSet<Long> timestamps = new TreeSet<>();
  private final long timeout = TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(5);
  private final int threshold = 10;
  public synchronized void event() {
    final long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    timestamps = timestamps.tailSet(now - timeout);
    timestamps.add(now);
    if (timestamps.size() > threshold) throw new OverloadException();
  }
}

class OverloadException extends RuntimeException { }
```

Comment: Let me give an example. I want to stop getting messages if an event occurs 10 times with in 5 minute time interval.

Answer (score 0):

Since your example above shows a rather low rate of events (10 events in 5 minutes), I would create a Queue of X timestamps. Each new message that arrives:

1. Pop off the Queue if it is full
2. Push onto the queue the current timestamp
3. If the stack is full and the difference between the Xth timestamp and the 1st timestamp is within the given interval, issue an alert!